# Domain of a graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Do all values in the domain of a function need to be on the graph if the function is injective?

For example, is the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{(x-5)^2}$ injective if the domain is N plus? There is no value at $x=5$, so the function cannot be surjective, but does it satisfy the domain requirement?

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(4)=f(6)=1$, so it's not injective.

Answer (score 0):

Correction: $5$ cannot be in the *domain* of the function, since your function is not defined when the denominator is equal to zero.

The function is not injective. Note for example that $f(4) = f(6).$

Comment: If 5 is not in the domain, can the domain even be N plus?

Comment: The domain is all numbers for which the function is defined, and hence, the domain is $\mathbb N^+ - \{5\}$.

Answer (score -1):

You can't speak of surjectivity without explicity stating the range. That's the space in which the image lies, and it could be larger than the image. In fact, a function is surjective if and only if the image equals the range. So the rule can be the same, but if you enlarge the range, you will lose surjectivity.

Comment: I think the term "co-domain" is often used for the (possibly) larger set in which the image lies. I've seen "range" used synonymously with "image" more often.

Comment: The terminology in this regard is not universally established. I'm aware that "range" is used differently by various authors. But I've always seen it said that if $f:A\rightarrow B$, then $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $B$ is the range of $f$. The image of $f$ is $f(A)$, which lies in the range.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to point out the other usage, in case the questioner was more familiar with it. I guess I don't know which is really more common. What I've always seen is different from what you've always seen. Is it a U.S./Europe thing? My math education has been in Texas and in Oregon.

Comment: My professor said that co-domain is the image, or the set of points mapped to, whereas range is the set of points that could be mapped to. But I don't understand how this works with surjectivity.

Comment: That's how I've seen it used. "Surjective" just means $f(A)=B$ (instead of just $f(A)\subset B$). It's also known as "onto" because a surjective function maps the domain *onto* the range, not just *into* it. For example, the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=\sin x$ is not surjective, but restricting the *range* to get another function  $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [-1,1]$ given by $h(x)=\sin x$ is indeed surjective. They aren't the same function because the ranges are different, even though they give exactly the same values and have the same domain.